# One function gets called without being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

A very weird thing is happening in my program. One of my function `goToLoginVC` is getting called. However, it shouldn't be called so I put break points on all the places that calls this function to see where exactly it is getting called from. The weird thing is.... None of the places I put breakpoints on gets executed. This is telling me that this `goToLoginVC` function is getting called without getting called by me?! I have triple checked that I have put break points on all places with goToLoginVC function by doing ctrl+shift+f in my program.

It is also weird that my program is breaking (error) on a function inside goToLoginVC even though I don't see why it could break on it as the "remove" was never printed out.

[image: goToLoginVC]

```
   func removeCurrentUserDataFromDisk() {
    print("remove")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(KEY_USER_EMAIL)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(KEY_USER_PASSWORD)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(KEY_USER_UID)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(KEY_FACEBOOK_TOKENSTRING)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(KEY_GOOGLE_IDTOKENSTR)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(KEY_GOOGLE_ACCESSTOKENSTR)
}
```

It is a pretty broad question. So I don't want to flood the question with all my code. However, I was wondering if there is some sort of explanation to this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that function.  When it stops, check the call stack.

Comment: I found out that the function INDEED never gets called by me. However, it was triggered because I didnt have completion block in one of my functions and the program somehow gets confuses and decided it needs to go into that code (Is that possible?). After putting in completion block, the code works as expected...